# Using vb.net in automation of HTML5 web browser

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a html page which I want to automate. I don't want to use browser control as it has problems when it comes to dialog windows. Is it possible to attach my vb/C# program to a existing web browser(IE)

I am planning to use htmlDocument2 of MSHTML library. Anyidea how to do it? Is there any other option?

Comment: What do you mean by "Automate". Can you update your question to be more specific in terms of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Shiva Say there is a very simple page with 2 input elements and a button. The user will fill the two elements and click on the button. It should be recorded and played back. I don't want anykind of readymade code/product. I know it can be done via MSHTML, Just wanted to know the correct approach.

Comment: There are external tools like Selenium that do this for FireFox. I imagine there's something similar for IE. You can probably Google "selenium IE" to get started...